# Using React Native with Git

Tags: git, react-native

I'm working on a React Native Project with a few other people. We share a common repository, but it seems like we frequently have to reinstall dependencies and we have a lot of problems with Xcode. Often, when one person installs a new dependency, the rest of us spend a long time trying to get it to work. Some of our dependencies require drag-and-drop installation into Xcode.

Is there a good way to handle a React Native git workflow (or perhaps other tools more suitable for it) or a way to ensure that your React Native dependencies are properly passed through git?

Answer (score 2):

if you are not using homebrew, you can introduce it in your project.

please check the website http://brew.sh/

Comment: I am using homebrew globally for installations from time to time. What is helpful about homebrew for React Native specifically? or how would I use it to benefit my projects?